# How to upload tweet post with image correctly

Tags: java, android, twitter

I'm trying to implement image uploading function in my Android application with Twitter API. I saw many examples like:

```
    private void uploadImage(File imagefile, final String tweettext){
    TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", imagefile);
    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = new TwitterApiClient(twitterSession);
    MediaService mediaservice = twitterApiClient.getMediaService();
    mediaservice.upload(typedFile, null, null, new Callback<Media>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Media> result) {
            postTweet(tweettext, result.data.mediaIdString);
            tweetMediaFile = null;
            iv1.setImageDrawable(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Medienupload fehlgeschlagen. Bitte erneut versuchen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

But since in new version of Twitter API another parameters for MediaService.upload (RequestBody, RequestBody, RequestBody), I'm trying to do like this:

```
private void uploadImage(File imagefile, final String tweettext) throws IOException {

    RequestBody rb = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imagefile);
    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = new TwitterApiClient(twitterSession);
    MediaService mediaservice = twitterApiClient.getMediaService();
    Response<Media> uploadResponse = mediaservice.upload(rb, null, null).execute();

    if (uploadResponse.isSuccessful()) {
        postTweet(tweettext, uploadResponse.body().mediaIdString);
        tweetMediaFile = null;
        iv1.setImageDrawable(null);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(TweetPostActivity.this, "Medienupload fehlgeschlagen. Bitte erneut versuchen.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

It doesn't work for me - the `mediaIdString` from the response (`uploadResponse.body().mediaIdString`) is empty.  Any ideas where I did mistake? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: i see that im trying to get mediaIdString from my response(uploadResponse.body().mediaIdString), but i get empty value, thats why i guess my method doesnt work. Hm maybe i should find another way to get my mediaId.

Comment: ok now i see where is my problem. I get IOException at:
Response<Media> uploadResponse = mediaservice.upload(rb, null, null).execute();
Any suggestions how to use mediaservice.upload properly?